# Creating an SSRS table from Unpivoted data Source

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, datatables, unpivot

I am trying to create a table on SSRS using an unpivoted data source. The table structure looks like the below:

```
Date        AgentName   Manager   KPIName       KPIValue
2018-04-23  John Doe    Jane Doe  LeadsRaised   5
2018-04-23  John Doe    Jane Doe  CallsTaken    20
2018-04-23  John Doe    Jane Doe  Registrations 5
```

Essentially I need to make a table that looks like the below which uses calculations from the `KPIValue` column and then displays the answer in one column. I know this is possible with Tableau, howver for the life of me I cannot work out how to recreate this on Report Builder:

The out put table I would like to look like the below:

```
Date       AgentName Manager  CalltoLeads%            Registration%
2018-04-23 John Doe  Jane Doe (LeadsRaised/CallsTaken)(Registrations/CallsTaken)
```

Anyone know how I can set up this type of table using the unpivoted data set shown above? The option of pivoting the data is not there as I have many different `KPINames` from different campaigns which all need to plug into the same type of table.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to SQL, you can do this is SSRS.
Step 1:
1)  For each value you need, create a field in the query that looks like this:

`For Field Name - LeadsRaised
    =iif(Dataset1.KPIName.Value =  "Leads Raised", Dataset1.KPIValue.value,0)`

2)  Once you have defined all the fields you need, you should create a total on the report by Date/Agent Name.  You can then create a formula on the line for each calculation you need:

`for the field CallToLead%
    =Max(LeadsRaised)/max(CallsTaken)`